# Jetty 8 set "session-timeout" without web.xml?

Tags: jetty, session-timeout, embedded-jetty

I'm trying to set the `session-timeout` value in an embedded Jetty 8 instance.

With embedded Jetty, how can I programmatically set the `session-timeout` value that would otherwise be set in the web.xml as follows:

```
 <session-config>
     <session-timeout>15</session-timeout>
 </session-config>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Access the session handling / management on your WebAppContext and set it.

```java
WebAppContext app = new WebAppContext(....);
... 
app.getSessionHandler().getSessionManager().setMaxInactiveInterval(timeout);
```

This is how [Jetty itself does it](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-8.1.14.v20131031/jetty-webapp/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/StandardDescriptorProcessor.java#L667-L672).

Note: [`SessionManager.setMaxInactiveInterval(int)`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/9.3.14.v20161028/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/SessionManager.html#setMaxInactiveInterval-int-) is in seconds, not milliseconds.

Answer (score 4):

**2019-05-11**

For Jetty version 9.4.12.v20180830 with the following `ServletContextHandler` setup, this is:

```
ServletContextHandler webappContext = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
... 
webappContext.getSessionHandler().setMaxInactiveInterval(timeout_in_sec);
```

(There is no intermediate call to `getSessionManager()`)